# Como puedo registrar una serie numérica iniciada por cero con php y mysql, por ejemplo 0100?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer esto para realizar el registro de un comprobante fiscal, el asunto es que debo registrarlo de una manera que cuando utilice uno el que le siga le sume un número a la serie anterior, es decir; si facture con la serie 0100 que en la siguiente factura que decida usar el comprobante me salga 0101 osea le sume un número a la serie anterior, lo intente con tipo de dato entero y al registrar le elimina el 0 que va delante y así no me sirve y lo intente poniendo en la base de datos ese campo de tipo text y cuando lo traigo con javascript lo convierto usando la función `number(respuesta["serie_usada"])` y así me permite sumarle uno a pesar de que venga de la base de datos de un campo tipo text, pero también elimina el cero delante como cuando uso el tipo de dato integer.

Comment: Aquí aplica el principio de **separación de intereses** y has de distinguir *persistencia* de *presentación*. Usa entero y `AUTO_INCREMENT` en MySQL y formatea al generar el HTML. Cuando guardas un número formateado en la base de dato resuelves un problema de presentación en la persistencia, con el costo de reconvertir cadenas a números y viceversa.

Comment: Gracias de antemano hermano por tu aporte, aunque si pudieras explicarme un poco más detallado, resulta que soy nuevo en este y voy en proceso de aprendizaje

Answer (score 0):

debes leer primero la base de datos, esta forma de hacerlo falla a la hora de generar un id único actual, ya lo he hecho.! lo que debes hacer es detener la base de datos y nadie puede seguir facturando, porque perderías la secuencia del identificador con respecto a la factura, es decir el numero a imprimir debe coincidir con la que esta en la factura impresa por la imprenta, ya ese método paso a la historia.

si usas serie-numeroFactura 0100-0055 puede usar dos campos y no te romperás la cabeza exitos

Comment: Si, lo tengo serie de inicio y serie final y una tabla detalle de comprobante donde guardo el ID de la factura, ID del comprobante registrado y la serie usada para cuando voy a facturar nuevamente me traiga la última serie usada y me le sume 1, pero le elimina el cero delante y en ves de decir 0101 pone 101, elimina el cero

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el campo correctamente formateado, creo que sólo necesitas utilizar la función *lpad*:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (columna_1) VALUES (LPAD( columna_1, 4, '0' ));
```

Lo que hace esta función es que rellena por la izquierda un determinado valor con otro valor hasta tener una longitud determinada:

```
LPAD( valor_inicial, longitud_final, 'valor_relleno' )
```

Comment: Puedo registrarla bien poniéndola de tipo text el problema es cuando la voy a mostrar en el cambio de tipo text en la vista que cuando pasa por la función number de javascript le quita el cero cuando hago la suma, le hice un console.log antes de mostrarlo y de allá viene bien el 0100 pero cuando le sumó 1 dentro de la función number se lo elimina

Comment: Entonces el problema es relativo a javascript, no a php/mysql. Lo que debes hacer es, sabiendo el número de dígitos de las facturas, comprobar si el número que te devuelve la DB tiene esa longitud o no. En caso de no tenerla (tendrá que ser menor), haz una función que recoja la cadena y vaya poniendo ceros al principio hasta tener el número de dígitos que tienen las facturas